# Meeting probability of two bankers: uniform distribution puzzle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, puzzle, uniform-distribution

> Two bankers each arrive at the station at some random time between 5PM
>   and 6PM (arrival time for each of them is uniformly distributed). They
>   stay exactly five minutes and then leave. What is the probability that
>   they will meet on a given day?

I am not sure how to go about modelling this problem as uniform distribution and solving it. Appreciate any help.

Here is how I start with it: Assume banker A arrives X minutes after 5PM and B arrives Y minutes after 5PM. Both X and Y are uniformly distributed between 5PM and 6PM. So pdf of X, Y is $\frac{1}{60}$. Now A and B will meet if $|X - Y| < 5$.

So required probability is $P(|X - Y| < 5)$ = Integral of joint distribution function of $|X - Y|$ from $0$ to $5$?

Now not sure how to write the equation from this point onwards and solve it.

Answer: $\frac {23}{144}$

Comment: Do you know how to solve multivariate probabilities in general. That is, to find the region you have to integrate your multivariate distribution over and then to calculate the integral?

Comment: @Marc I am trying to get my head around how to model multivariate equations. I believe integral is next step which should be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If $f_{X,Y}$ is the multivariate pdf then you want to solve the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{60}\int_{\max\{0,x-5\}}^{\min\{60,x+5\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx.
$$

Comment: So $f_{X,Y} = \frac{1}{60} \frac{1}{60}$ . How did you arrive at limits of inner integral. Pls explain

Comment: Well $x$ has to be 5 minutes from $y$. However they also both have to be between 5 and 5 PM. Thats why the min and max are there, to make sure $x$ and $y$ satisfy both these requirements.

Comment: sorry still not clear to me.

Comment: We have two equations: $x-5 < y < x+5$ and $0<y<60$. We want $y$ to satisfy both, so we have to take the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you also help with the outer integral. The inner one will give $$
\int_{0}^{60}\frac{[min(60, x+5) - max(0, x-5)]}{3600}dx.
$$

Comment: Easiest is to split the integral from 0-5, 5-55, 55-60.

Comment: $$
\int_{0}^{60}\frac{[min(60, x+5) - max(0, x-5)]}{3600}dx = \int_{0}^{5}\frac{x+5-0}{3600}dx + \int_{5}^{55}\frac{x+5-x+5}{3600}dx + \int_{55}^{60}\frac{60-x+5}{3600}dx = \frac{\int_{0}^{5}(x+5)dx + \int_{5}^{55}10dx + \int_{55}^{60}(65-x)dx}{3600}
$$

Comment: This integral yields correct answer as $\frac{23}{144}$. Thanks @Marc

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

We will consider the situation in terms of minutes. We notice that that they will meet only if $|X-Y|\leq 5/60$, where $X,Y$ is the time of arrival as a fraction of the hour. We notice that $X,Y\overset{iid}{\sim} \text{unif(0,1)}$. Then they problem becomes
$$P(|X-Y| \leq 5/60).$$
It will help to draw a picture. No integration required.

---

You can do it considering the $X,Y\overset{iid}\sim\text{unif}(1,60)$ too.
[image]

Notice that we want the blue part. Also, notice that we can instead consider the complement
\begin{align*}
P(|X-Y|<5) &= P(-5<X-Y<5)\\
&=P(\text{blue})\\
&= 1-P(\text{Not blue})\\
&= 1-2\bigg[\underbrace{(1/2)\cdot55\cdot55\cdot 60}_{(1)}/\underbrace{60^3}_{(2)}\bigg]\\
&= 1-\left(\frac{55}{60}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{23}{144}
\end{align*}

where in

1. That is the volume of one wedge
2. That is the entire volume.

Comment: Can you show how to do it using Integral. Thanks

Comment: No, I specifically did not want to integrate. You are simply going to be finding the volume above the blue strip. You're going to have to break up the blue strip into 3 regions.

Comment: @Em.  : Suppose a bomb will explode at a random moment from 5 PM to 6.05 PM . What will be the probability that both bankers will be there at that moment ?

Comment: @mrwong Please use the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button to ask a new question and include your own work and understanding of the problem. Otherwise, your question will be closed.

Comment: @Em. Thanks for  your  reply. But there is a reason why I don't  ask by myself. I  believe not so many people can get a correct answer to my question . If you are interested you are welcome to give an answer here at any time .

Comment: @Em. The answer is about 0.006